# Java Pattern Program Error

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to make a program which gives this output:

```
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```

where the maximum number of stars is 'n'. however, something is wrong with my code here. help will be appreciated.

```
class test
{
    public static void main(int n)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for(int x=n;x>=1;x--)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there - think of it as an upright triangle followed by an upside down triangle. In the first one, there are N rows, each row having an increasing number of asterisks, from one up to N. In the second one, each row has a decreasing number of asterisks, from N-1 down to 1:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; --i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This could, of course, be made much more elegant by extracting the inner `for` loop which creates each row to its own method:

```
private static void printRow (int i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
       System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.println();
}

private static void main (String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        printRow(i);
    }
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; --i) {
        printRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it. If you _had_ to do it all inside one loop, you could, with a bunch of math... but there's no reason to do that when you can split it into smaller, easier parts.

Comment: Wow, you wrote EXACTLY the same come I did seconds before I posted... even the variables, scary shit! +1 for thinking alike